# Trying to make a latin phrase with multiple meanings

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Does the phrase "Alea sapit fortem" make sense grammatically, and does it make sense period? I wanted it to mean something along the lines of "The die savors chance," but to have a deeper meaning based on the origins of alea and fors, eg "A bone understands that which it carries."

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use *fors* in the accusative like that (except perhaps if it is personified). That's at least how I interpret the [L&S](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/fors) entry.